# DocuSign OAuth Code grant Authentication callback UrL not found

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, docusignapi

I have a web application that has a public pages and a secure administrative part. For the public pages I'm using JWT authentication and DocuSign embedded signing, this is working fine. Now I'm adding an administrative section that I want to use Authorization Code Grant. I have the authentication code copied from your launcher-csharp sample application. The login action is doing the Challange() and I get the DocuSign login. The problem is that I'm not getting the OAuth OnCreatedTicket event. What is happening is Docusign is returning the callback url and my application is throwing a 404 not found on /ds/callback? My application is an asp.net 6. I'm using DocuSign.eSign.dll 5.9.0. When debugging the DocuSign launcher-csharp sample app the services.AddAuthentication and services.AddOAuth code is executed on startup. But in my test app the AddAuthentication and AddOAuth breakpoints aren't hit on startup, but only when I do a login Challange(). I think this my be the problem could the OAuth middleware events are not getting registered?

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. I must have looked at this many times. In the startup.cs I had   app.UseAuthorization();. I replaced it with  app.UseAuthentication(); and everything works. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

You need code link this in [startup.cs](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/Startup.cs):

```
    .AddOAuth("DocuSign", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["DocuSign:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["DocuSign:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/ds/callback");

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["DocuSign:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
        options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["DocuSign:TokenEndpoint"];
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["DocuSign:UserInformationEndpoint"];
```

Comment: yes, my code is almost verbatim in the DocuSign startup.cs.  I get the DocuSign login and the callback with the code and state query parameters. But I get: No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7264/ds/callback?code=arefe. . . Seems like the OAuth middleware is not seeing the callback. I never get any OAuthEvents.

Comment: Do you have DSController.cs in your code base?

Comment: [Route("ds/[action]")]
attribute at the top of this class to make sure it gets these calls

Comment: Is your project .NET Core? same ASP.MVP project type as the quickstart?

Comment: My original VS project is asp.net 6 mvc, it has the same behavior. I created another asp.net core 3.1 just like the DocuSign quickstart program, I added the Docusign.eSign.dll 5.9.0. Added the code for authentication. If you look at the DocuSign Quickstart launcher-csharp program the DSController doesn't have a callback action. The OAuth middleware should intercept the callback and the OAuthEvents handle the response from Docusign. I have other applications that use Identity server for OAuth and the OAuth middleware handles the callback.

Comment: I see you're good. Glad to hear that